# How do I automate multiple CSV exports with FOR loop in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to export a series of csv files by symbol

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exportcrypto()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
  declare
    irec record;
BEGIN
FOR irec IN
    SELECT DISTINCT symbol FROM daily
    LOOP
   EXECUTE 
   'COPY (SELECT o as open, h as high, l as low, c as close, v as volume, 0.0 as dividend, 1.0 as split FROM daily WHERE symbol =' || irec.symbol || ')
   TO "C:/Users/d/Documents/sdata/db_exports/crypto/' || irec.symbol || '.csv" WITH DELIMITER "," CSV HEADER;'
END LOOP;
END
$func$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'm getting a variety of errors like syntax at END LOOP or at TO and have tried variations of the copy string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace double quotes with single quotes and delete the semicolon, and unless `symbol` is numeric (assumed not), add quotes around that too:

```
EXECUTE 
'COPY (SELECT o as open, h as high, l as low, c as close, v as volume, 0.0 as dividend, 1.0 as split FROM daily WHERE symbol = ''' || irec.symbol || ''') TO ''C:/Users/d/Documents/sdata/db_exports/crypto/' || irec.symbol || '.csv'' WITH DELIMITER '','' CSV HEADER';
```

A literal single quote `'` is coded as a doubled single quote `''`.

Also rather than function that returns void, define it as a procedure, and `LANGUAGE` goes first too, so the whle thing should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE exportcrypto()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $func$
  declare irec record;
BEGIN
FOR irec IN SELECT DISTINCT symbol FROM daily LOOP
    EXECUTE 
'COPY (SELECT o as open, h as high, l as low, c as close, v as volume, 0.0 as dividend, 1.0 as split FROM daily WHERE symbol = ''' || irec.symbol || ''') TO ''C:/Users/d/Documents/sdata/db_exports/crypto/' || irec.symbol || '.csv'' WITH DELIMITER '','' CSV HEADER';
END LOOP;
END
$func$
```

Comment: @Bohemain You might want to mention that procedures are valid only in Postgres v11 or higher. The language specification can go either before or after. It is basically a preference